# JPA: Working on copied Lists also modifies the ParentCollection

Tags: java, jpa

I have a weird problem. If I assign an entity collection referenced from child (not owning side of the relation) to an entity property and remove an object the behaviour is that when I reinvoke the getter of this collection I see that entity was removed when I call the getter `getKomponenten()`

```
        // This is an excerpt of my Entity Paket
        @OneToMany(mappedBy = "paket", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, targetEntity = Komponente.class, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
            private List<Komponente> komponenten;

            public void setKomponenten(List<Komponente> komponenten) {
                this.komponenten = komponenten;
            }

            public List<Komponente> getKomponenten() {
                return komponenten;
            }

        // Komponente (the owning side)
         @ManyToOne(cascade = { CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE }, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
            private Paket paket;

        // Excerpt from the ManagedBean
        @ManagedBean
        @ViewScoped
        public class PaketController implements Serializable {
         private List<Komponente> komponenteInSelectedPaketList;
        private Komponente selectedKomponente;
        private Paket selectedPaket;

        public void removeKomponenteFromPaket() { 
                this.komponenteInSelectedPaketList.remove(this.selectedKomponente);
    // Next row manipulates the referenced entity collectin as well
                List<Komponente> example = this.selectedPaket.getKomponenten();
                // example contains the list without the removed Komponente from the other list (call by reference like behaviour)
            }
    }
```

Any hints? Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not like call by reference. Call by reference means that changes to a method argument are visible to the caller. You are not seeing changes to the method argument, which is a pointer. That pointer hasn't changed. It points to the same object throughout. What you are seeing is that *changes to an object through a pointer* are  visible. That's what happens with pointers.

A little research on call by value vs. call by reference should help you get clear. Meanwhile, just remember that all method arguments in Java are passed by value.

Comment: I know. But removing an entity instance from a copied list also removes it from the list I got back calling the getter getKomponenten()